# What's that tool for knitting, stitching or sewing?

Tags: tool-identification

During clearing out the home of my deceased parents, I found some plates which are tools for either knitting, stitching or sewing. First I thought they were part of the knitting machine Brother KH-588, but then I found others in a completely different place, so I assume that they are not related to this machine. These are thin metal plates of about 10 cm in size each, with some sort of clamps on them. Does someone have a clue what these things are, and what they are used for?

[image]

Comment: They don't look like anything shown in the manual for that machine ( https://mostlyknittingmachines.weebly.com/uploads/8/4/6/7/846749/brother_kh552___kh558_user_manual.pdf ), what else did you find them near? Machines, supplies, other tools? Those could lend a hint.

Comment: Not an answer, because the devices are missing the holes that would make these Kumihimo Disks. When extended, the fingers would hold threads/yarn for weaving, then slid inward to easily release the work. They may yet be a weaving device, but I'm unable to identify them accurately. A local weaver asked me a couple of years ago to design something just like this.

Comment: @AllisonC Funnily enough, I found the wool winding tool depicted on page 8 (page 9 of the PDF file) nearby other plates. I did not know that this tool belongs to the knitting machine until I saw the PDF file. Nevertheless, I also found several knitting needles there, so the occurence of these plates along with the wool winding tool may still not tell us that they are related to each other.

Comment: Good information, if not particularly helpful! Hopefully the PDF will be useful to you with the machine, and hopefully someone will recognize these devices as well.

Comment: Having done some sinnet and knot work these look like they could be used to keep the strings separated while tying a complex knot like a fancy button.

Answer (score 2):

I think these items are shapes to make yarn flowers and a kind of lace for which I can not find the name.

This search results page ([link to pinterest search results](https://nl.pinterest.com/pin/184788390935058081/)) shows a series of different shapes which each have a set of pins sticking up or out for string to be wound around, going from a stick over the middle of the shape, and then to one on the other side of the shape, forming a flower shape which has all yarn crossing in the middle. That middle is next sewn together, so the flower gets structure.

When used for that lace method there can be more creative winding and a lot more 'sewing' or embroidery over the yarn.

Your templates are up-side-down in the picture, you would work on the flat side.

The system in these templates seems to allow to retract the 'sticking out' pins.